# how to implement two layer of layout in Phalcon?

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm using Phalcon and Volt ,
this is folder Structure in my project for layout

```
app/views/layouts/default.volt
```

and structure is like this
[image]

default.volt is main layout that come with all pages .

now I need another layer of Layout to come with all pages.

this structure would be like this

[image]

I think it's clear with these photos .

So, How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

your "main layout":
app/views/[controller].volt

your "another layout":
app/views/layouts/[controller].volt

your "page content":
app/views/[controller]/[action].volt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can write in your views/index.volt:

```
{% include 'layouts/' ~ config.view.theme ~ '/header' %}
{% include 'layouts/' ~ config.view.theme ~ '/body' %}
{% include 'layouts/' ~ config.view.theme ~ '/footer' %}
```

So, you can manage your theme from your controller base like:

```
function initialize()
{
    $controller = $this->dispatcher->getControllerName();
    switch ($controller) {
        case 'controller1':
        case 'controller2':
            $this->config->view->theme = 'mytheme_with_menu';
            break;
        case 'controller3':
        case 'controller4':
            $this->config->view->theme = 'mytheme_without_menu';
            break;
    }
}
```